# fetch data based on another table

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table as users and table as zebra for friend list. I want t fetch the details of all friends who are connected to a particular user

Here is the code i am using. But its not working.

```
     $user_friend_pro_query= "Select * From users Where user_id    IN    (Select zebra_id From zebra Where user_id='$uid');";
    $user_friend_pro_fetch = $conn->query($user_friend_pro_query);

     while($friend_pro_rows = $user_friend_pro_fetch->fetch_assoc())
   {
   $friend_id=$friend_pro_rows['user_id'];
   $user_avatar_thumb=$friend_pro_rows['user_avatar_thumb'];

  ?><li> <a href="memeber-profile.php?user_id=<?php echo $friend_id ?>">    <img src="<?php echo $user_avatar_thumb ; ?>"   width="42" height="42"></a></li>
```

Please help

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get any errors?

Comment: What is wrong then?

Comment: It is nit displaying anything

Comment: is the query correct?

Comment: What's displayed if you call "Select * From users Where user_id    IN    (Select zebra_id From zebra Where user_id='$uid');" before the start of this code?

Comment: Now am running the query with user_id='48270', still its not displaying anything. a blank page only

Comment: Hate to ask the obvious but are you sure there is a result? What happens if you run the query directly on the database?

Comment: Also, I don't see a closing bracket for your 'While'  statement. Is there one?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to change this code segment

```
(Select zebra_id From zebra Where user_id='$uid');";
```

to

```
(Select zebra_id From zebra Where user_id='".$uid."')";
```

This will escape the $uid variable, which might cause a problem.